# Why does 'foo' + false ? 'bar' : 'baz' evaluate to 'bar'

Tags: javascript

I removed the parenthesis from the following ternary:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/' + (isMap ? 'json' : 'javascript'));
```

And the test failed with:

```
Error: expected 'json' to equal 'application/javascript'
```

At first I thought this is just some wired Node.js issue, but it seems that:

```
'foo' + false ? 'bar' : 'baz'
```

Evaluates to 'bar' in Firefox and Chrome.

So my question is:

1. What happened to the first part of my string.
2. Why am I getting the `true` value of the ternary operation when I'm passing `false`.

Comment: the `false` is first converted to a `string` and then concatenated to the `foo` string, since this succeeds it returns true and you will end up with 'bar'

Comment: @NickVanderhoven you should write a real answer.

Comment: Operator precedence rules exist because JS can't know if you intend `("foo" + false) ? "bar" : "baz"` or `"foo" + (false ? "bar" : "baz)`. Grouping with parens exists to make code explicitly clear and/or to override the operator precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'foo' + false ? 'bar' : 'baz'
```

concatenating 'foo' + false is evaluating to true because false is treated as a string so string 'foofalse' is true.

its a duplicate and the accepted answer there is a good explanation.

[Using the ternary operator with string concatenation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847853/using-the-ternary-operator-with-string-concatenation)

Answer (score 0):

The `false` is first converted to a string and then concatenated to the `foo` string, since this succeeds, it returns `true` and you will end up with `bar`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not passing a FALSE.  You are adding a FALSE object to a string.  In this case, JavaScript would see that as an empty variable.  It's not a boolean, like you're thinking.

There is no actual evaluation going on here to resolve to false, so it will simply return true.